# Is $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{2/3})$ an unramified extension?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$ adic numbers. I am wondering if $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{2/3})$ an unramified extension or not? Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: I tried factoring $(p)$ over the ring of integers of the extension, but I could not make it factor using $p^{2/3}$. So I thought maybe I am missing something...

Comment: Try thinking in terms of valuations?

Comment: @JohnnyT: What do you mean by "I could not make it factor using $p^{2/3}$"? I suspect that what you are missing is that you disbelieved (or otherwise dismissed) the significant feature of this field that this line of thought leads to.

Comment: I would think that $\Bbb Q_p(p^{2/3})=\Bbb Q_p(p^{1/3})$. Do you not think so?

Comment: @Lubin Oh geeezzzz... Yes!